# Jaspersoft increase space between TextFields with element height

Tags: jasper-reports

I have two TextField elements placed one above another (bordered with red, empty now)
[1 step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM739.jpg)
When I add some text in first element, it stretch with content. Second elemetm moving down
[2 step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzKHx.jpg)
But when I add some large string in second element, it stretchs and add some space between element. This scpace depends on height of second element
[3 step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPSrB.jpg)
How I can stretch second element without increasing space between elements
Both elements placed in one band
Thank you

Comment: Put a red border in the labels too. maybe one of them is stretching

Comment: I tried, It's only space increasing